# How can i replace single image in gridview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a gridview with different images. While i click on particular imageButton it's download and save into my SDcard folder. After completing download this image fetch from downloaded folder and open in another activity but i want to replace on particular gridview cell.

I done following task:

1. Save image to SDcard folder.
2. Read image from SDcard folder.
3. Open in another activity.

But how to replace on particular gridview cell.

This is my watercolor_fragment.xml it has griview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, is my Watercolor.java which inflate watercolor_fragment.xml

```
public class Watercolor extends Fragment {
    View view;
    String[] name={"FIRST","SECOND","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","ELEVEN","TWELVE","THRTEEN","FOUREEN","FIFTEEN","SIXTEEN"};
    public int[] mThumbIds={R.drawable.natureone,R.drawable.naturetwo,
                                     R.drawable.naturethree,R.drawable.naturefour,
                                 R.drawable.naturefive,R.drawable.naturesix,
                                 R.drawable.natureseven,R.drawable.natureight,
            R.drawable.naturenine,R.drawable.natureten,R.drawable.natureleven,R.drawable.naturetwelve,
            R.drawable.naturethrtineen,R.drawable.naturefourthyeen,R.drawable.naturefifteen,R.drawable.naturesixteen};
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.watercolor_fragment, container, false);

        GridView gridView=(GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext(),name,mThumbIds));

//        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(), FullImaeActivity.class);
//                Log.e("Position",""+position);
//                i.putExtra("id", position);
//                startActivity(i);
//            }
//        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here, is my custome_image.xml which have imageview and imageButton which set on each cell of gridview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/naturefour"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btndownload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here, is my ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] name;
    Context context;
    int[] imageId;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context,String[] name, int[] imageId) {
        this.name=name;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.name.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        ImageButton btnDownload;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        final View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_image, null);
        holder.btnDownload = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btndownload);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), imageId[position]);
        int height = (bitmap.getHeight() * 512 / bitmap.getWidth());
        Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512, height, true);
        holder.img.setImageBitmap(scale);
        holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    //File root = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "IMAGES");

                    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/.IMAGES/");
                    if (!root.exists()) {
                        root.mkdirs();
                    }

                    File file = new File(root + File.separator + position + ".jpeg");
                    Log.e("Path", "" + file);
                    file.createNewFile();

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(rowView.getContext(), FullImaeActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("id", position);

                try{
                    File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/.IMAGES/");

                    Log.e("File path",""+root);
                    File file=new File(root,File.separator+position+".jpeg");

                    if(!file.exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), "Please, Download First!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("FINAL PATH", "" + file);

                        FileInputStream streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(streamIn);
                        streamIn.close();
                        Intent intent=new Intent(rowView.getContext(),FullImaeActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", bitmap);
                        rowView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here, is my FullImageActivity.java

```
ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_imae);
        mVisible = true;

        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap)intent.getParcelableExtra("id");

        Watercolor adapter=new Watercolor();
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.full_image);
        //imageView.setImageResource(adapter.mThumbIds[id]);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

How can i solve out please, Help me!!!

Comment: Tag your `gridview cell` with the id of the downloaded image. after downloading get the `gridview cell` by `Tag` and replace the image as `drawable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I would try to give you a quick solution, but it would be nice if you want to read up on MVC where you can represent data as Java Objects. Based on the state of these objects you would modify your Views. The idea would be to have a String field used for storing the path of the img in the directory(sdcard/img) and an int field (R.id.img). based on the value of your string field you can either use it or instead use it from your int field.
for e.g.

```
public class Img{
    String name;
    String imgSdCardPath;
    int imgResourceValue;
}
```

your adapter would then operate on the list of these Img Objects.

instead of `String[] name;`
 and `int[] imageId;` lists in your adapter you would have.

```
List<Img> imageList;
```

now you need a logic to set the image source based on the value of `String imgSdCardPath;` in your getView() method. if the imgSdCardPathIsPresent use the below code to get file from sdcard

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
```

otherwise do what you are doing.

remember to update your imgSdCardPath in your object when you are storing the image to sdcard, and call notififydatasetchanged of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try imageloader.jar?
Everything you have done and you want to do can replace by only one statement.`ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgUrl, holder.img);`

Answer (score 0):

try to have a look at Universal Image Loader here: [the github url](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

the features:

- Multithread image loading (async or sync)
- Wide customization of ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downloader, decoder, memory and disk cache, display image options, etc.)
- Many customization options for every display image call (stub images, caching switch, decoding options, Bitmap processing and displaying, etc.)
  Image caching in memory and/or on disk (device's file system or SD card)
- Listening loading process (including downloading progress)

hope to help you!

Answer (score 0):

[Android developer url] (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Attach the view reference while downloading with task and update it with task completion.